# I am sending mail with laravel 5.*. but it send whole html view code instead of html preview

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have created a view `contact-us` and mail class in controller as it is following. when i send mail it show the success message and send `view` `contact-us` as mail..

```
$data = ['name' => 'Sunny Mine'];

    Mail::send(['text' => 'mail.contact-us'], $data, function($msg){

        $msg->to('abc@gmail.com', 'Muhammad Ibrar receiver')->subject('Test Contact Us Form Mail');
        $msg->from('def@gmail.com', 'Muhammad Ibrar sender');

    });
```

it send whole html code including html tags but not a webpage preview.. can someone help me to send mail with web view please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forcing the view as text type. Remove the `'text'` type and it should work fine.

```
Mail::send('mail.contact-us', $data, function($msg) {
    $msg->to('abc@gmail.com', 'Muhammad Ibrar receiver')->subject('Test Contact Us Form Mail');
    $msg->from('def@gmail.com', 'Muhammad Ibrar sender');
});
```